# Devise - redirect to the user clicked after sign in, if the user is not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, redirect

I am using Devise in Rails 3. I have used `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to redirect to sign in if a user, not logged in, clicks a link. This works, but after login, it redirects back to the home page. Instead I want to redirect to the link the user clicked before redirection to login page. This is my code:

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout :layout_by_resource

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
      if current_user.admin?
        admin_event_types_path
      else
        home_path
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
  ..
  ..
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :token_authenticatable
  ..
  ..
end
```

**Update**

I tried this using answer from @dreamfall, but it is not redirecting as expected.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
    if current_user.admin?
      stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) ? stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) : admin_event_types_path 
    else
      stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) ? stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) : home_path
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Is there any built in configuration for this in Devise? If not, how will I go about this and where should I change the code?

Comment: If the authentication failed, add the url to the session and after authenticating the user, redirect to the url saved in the session and clear it.

Comment: @mohamed.magdy..right..but I dont know where to set the session as the code for this is in the devise gem.

Comment: Great, you can either override the authenticate_user! method or write your own authentication method.

Answer (score 1):

Devise provides functionality to redirect to stored in session url after signing in. Use `stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)` method in your `after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)` method.

Comment: do we need to store the url in the session manually or does just using   `stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)` in the method do the task..I have updated the code with what I have tried but it is not redirecting as expected..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved like this:

```
before_action :store_location

  def after_sign_in_path_for(*)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end

  private

  def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to 
    whatever the user last visited.
    return unless request.get?
    if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
        request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
        request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
        request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
    end
  end
```

This is basically intercepting all get requests and saving the url on the session of the user. After you login if you have a previous_url saved it will be redirected correctly.